# JQuery cancel animation when animating between values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `.animate()` to animate between two values with a step function. Since there's no selector, I can't use `.stop()`

```
        $({ Value: 50 }).animate({ Value: 0 }, {

            duration: 1000,

            step: function (val) {

                $('#SomeElement').css({

                    transform: "translateY(" + val + "px)"
                });
            }
        });
```

How can I stop this animation after it's launched?

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, I could find way to use with selectors (see snippet below).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      div {
        top: 100;
        left: 0;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="SomeElement"></div>

    <button>stop</button>

    <script>
      $('#SomeElement').animate({ top: 100 }, {

        duration: 2000,

        step: function (val) {

          $('#SomeElement').css({

            transform: "translateY(" + val + "px)"

          });

        }
      });

    $('button').click(function () {

      $('#SomeElement').stop();

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know my script works; the problem is how to stop the animation once it's started.

Comment: Perhaps you can help to clarify more on what you mean by `stop`. AS IN -

The `.animate()` script stops after running for the specified duration i.e. 1000. Changing that to say, 50 would mean, stop after 50 ms.

Comment: Stop the animation WHILE it's running.

Comment: Updated the answer with selectors alternative. Curiously, though, kindly help to shed light on perhaps why not using a selector is the intended? As I would think using a selector is in more harmony with the jQuery API.

Comment: It's for parralax scrolling, the function needs to work as I have it, meaning without selectors.